# validate a xml file against a xsd using php

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd, xml-parsing

how to validate a xml file against a xsd? there is domdocument::schemaValidate() but It does not tell where are the errors. is there any class for that? does it have any worth making that parser from scratch? or is it just reinventing he wheel,

Answer (score 29):

This code does the business:

```
$xml= new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML(<A string goes here containing the XML data>, LIBXML_NOBLANKS); // Or load if filename required
if (!$xml->schemaValidate(<file name for the XSD file>)) // Or schemaValidateSource if string used.
{
   // You have an error in the XML file
}
```

See the code in http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php To retrieve the errors.

I.e.

justin at redwiredesign dot com 08-Nov-2006 03:32 post.

Comment: i don't think it tells where the errors are and where does it failing and why it is failing .does it?

Comment: Unfortunately the PHP version makes use of libxml2 which does not support the XSD of the XSLT 2.0 specification...

Answer (score 13):

User contrib from http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php

**It works like a charm!**

> For more detailed feedback from DOMDocument::schemaValidate, disable
>   libxml errors and fetch error information yourself.  See
>   http://php.net/manual/en/ref.libxml.php for more info.

**example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    <child_string>This is an example.</child_string>
    <child_integer>Error condition.</child_integer>
</example>
```

**example.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="example">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="child_string" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="child_integer" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

function libxml_display_error($error)
{
    $return = "<br/>\n";
    switch ($error->level) {
        case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
            $return .= "<b>Warning $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
            $return .= "<b>Error $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
            $return .= "<b>Fatal Error $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
    }
    $return .= trim($error->message);
    if ($error->file) {
        $return .=    " in <b>$error->file</b>";
    }
    $return .= " on line <b>$error->line</b>\n";

    return $return;
}

function libxml_display_errors() {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        print libxml_display_error($error);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}

// Enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('example.xml');

if (!$xml->schemaValidate('example.xsd')) {
    print '<b>DOMDocument::schemaValidate() Generated Errors!</b>';
    libxml_display_errors();
}

?>
```

Comment: It looks like the code on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-validxphp/.

Comment: Sorry to post years later, but how could you change the code above to validate against a schema file (xsd) with dependencies on other schema files (xsd)?

Comment: Again years later ;) If you use `schemaValidate` it will resolve dependencies, if you use `schemaValidateSource` it wouldn't. In case you experience problems you might need to check the relative paths of the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete code snippet for displaying xsd validation errors:

```
    $xml = '<test/>';
    $xsd = '/path/to/xsd';
    // needed for getting errors
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $domDocument= new DOMDocument();
    $domDocument->loadXML($xml); 
    if (!$domDocument->schemaValidate($xsd)) {
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            print_r($error);
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }
```