# How to validate XML with XSLT in php

Tags: php, xml, xslt

We can validate XML file with XSD using

```
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->load('20140728-1035058.xml'); 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);     

if (!$xml->schemaValidate('anteilseignerliste_V6_1.xsd')) {
    print '<b>DOMDocument::schemaValidate() Generated Errors!</b>';
echo "<pre>";
    libxml_display_errors();
}
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
```

Same way how to **validate XML file with XSLT**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [validate a xml file against a xsd using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650377/validate-a-xml-file-against-a-xsd-using-php)

Comment: XSD is for validation; XSLT is for *transformation*.  Do you mean how to *transform* XML with XSLT?   (It is possible to write XSLT that performs validation -- as Schematron does -- but if that's your actual question, it's much too broad as stated.)